# caracter 'a' getting removed when I try to replace new line, tabs and consecutive spaces with a space

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, tr

Below is the command I'm typing

```
cat program.c | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\t' ' ' | tr -s [:space:] ' ' >unreadable.c
```

The output is

```
Hi w ssup. How re you doing bro Its nice to see you g in bro .
```

But the problem is character 'a' is getting removed from the file which should not happen.

Can anyone pls help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[:space:]` is a valid glob pattern (matching a single `'`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c`, or `e`), and you appear to have a file named `a` in your working directory that the pattern matches, so you are *really* running `tr -s a ' '` instead after the shell performs pathname expansion. Quote the pattern to prevent the shell from exanding it.

```
... | tr -s '[:space:]' ' ' >  unreadable.c
```

(Note that if there was no matching file, the default behavior is to treat the pattern literally, and your command would work as expected. However, there is a shell option you can set to treat non-matching patterns as an error, so it is good practice to always quote an argument to guarantee it is passed *literally* to a command.)

---

`[:space:]` already includes newlines and tabs, so you only need the one call to `tr`:

```
tr '[:space:]' ' ' < program.c > unreadable.c
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed like this:

```
cat program.c | sed -r "s/\n|\t|\s+/ /g" > unreadable.c
```